# w2ui - Inline edit grid with list. under grid i need to call onselect for each dropdown

Tags: jquery, grid, dropdown, w2ui

I am using [w2ui](http://w2ui.com/web/demo/grid) grid in-line edit with list and many other stuff.

How can I listen to the **onselect** event of an element ?

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
     name: 'grid',
     columns: [
        {
             field: 'fieldname',caption: 'caption',sortable: true,
             editable: {
                 type: 'list',
                 items: people,
                 showAll: true 
                }           
             }
     ],....
```

Comment: on select of rows / column ?

Comment: select of item in dropdown.

Comment: got it. answer is below. let me know if its work for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below and visit the link for detailed information.

```
w2ui.grid.on('change', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

OR

You can add this during grid creation as well.

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
    name    : 'grid',
    // . . . . . . . 
    onChange: function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }        
});
```

http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2grid.onChange

Comment: Added one more solution as well !